# Getting the request IP address with Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm using Pyramid framework and I want to access the IP address from which the request originated.  I assume it's in the request object (passed to every view function) somewhere, but I can't find documentation which tells me where it is.

Comment: it might be worth it to you to get comfy with webob. http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's in `request.remote_addr`.

You can find it in the [`pyramid.request`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.remote_addr) documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I saw that in the documentation, but I didn't realze that  "remote_addr" meant "IP address".  Why don't they just call it "IP address"?

Comment: Because "IP address" is ambiguous -- is that the server's address, the client's address, or something else? "remote_addr" is the address of the remote side, i.e. the client.

Answer (score 8):

You can use: [`request.client_addr`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.client_addr).

Comment: "It is possible for user agents to put someone else’s IP or just any string in HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR as it is a normal HTTP header. Forward proxies can also provide incorrect values (private IP addresses etc). You cannot “blindly” trust the result of this method to provide you with valid data unless you’re certain that HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR has the correct values. The WSGI server must be behind a trusted proxy for this to be true."  


So if I understand this correctly, you should use `remote_addr` unless you are behind a trusted proxy that sets a correct HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR.

Comment: @YannDinendal: Yes, you're right. Sorry if I didn't clarify this point.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use `request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']`